# ffmpeg and 2:35:1 aspect ratio

Tags: ffmpeg

Fast question.
I want to create a file with 2:35:1 a/r.
Is correct to use 2.3333?

```
ffmpeg -progress file.txt -i file.mpg -acodec mp3 -c:v mpeg4 -vtag DIVX -b:v 1500k -b:a 128k -y -aspect 2.3333 file.avi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-aspect 2.35` for 2.35:1 display aspect ratio.